# Why is Robot Unicorn Attack 2 telling me it's "offline"?

Tags: robot-unicorn-attack-2

I've been playing team RUA2 just fine for a while, but suddenly the game is telling me that I'm offline. How do I get it to go back online and avoid having it go "offline" again?